# Sudo has a different language than non-sudo

Tags: language-support

I installed the Japanese language some time ago to attempt to improve my Japanese, however since I had not good enough language I reverted it back. The problem is that now, the programs that I run using sudo as gparted are installed in Japanese. How can I revert this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some error happened last time, but when changing the language, I simply needed to press the "Apply system-wide" and problem solved.

Comment: Error? Probably you clicked that button when you switched to Japanese but not when you reverted back. ;)